# How the Visual Studio debugger infer Value inside watch window?

Tags: c#, watch

In the watch window for example I see:

> **Name**: task
>   **Value**: Id = 11, Status = WaitingToRun, Method = "Void`<`RetreiveFromCache`>`b__0()"
>   **Type**: System.Threading.Tasks.Task

So the `task` variable is of Type Task and I want to access to the same Value the debugger prints, particularly I am interested in the `Method` value (**RetreiveFromCache**)

However on the `task` variable I have only access to .Id, .Status, etc... but not .Method

Where does the `Method` value come from?

How can the debugger "infer" the `Method` value?

Comment: are you looking to dump entire value lists? or specific objects

Comment: Is this a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or some other kind of task? I can get the Id, Status and Type, but not the Method.

Comment: yep... It's exactly the Method value that I am looking for!

Comment: @spiderman77, I've edited my answer to show how you can obtain the Method to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Action` variable of the `Task` object is not accessible. What you can do, is create your own class that extends the functionality of `Task`, while exposing the Action (which holds the information about the method to run).

A quick example:

```
public class CustomTask : Task
{
    private Action m_action;

    public Action Action
    {
        get { return m_action; }
    }

    public CustomTask(Action action) : base(action)
    {
        m_action = action;
    }
}
```

Then in your code, you can use it like this:

```
CustomTask ct = new CustomTask(MyMethod);

Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Method: {1}, Status: {2}", ct.Id, ct.Action.Method, ct.Status);
//Prints: "ID: 1, Method: Void MyMethod(), Status: Created"

ct.Start();
Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Method: {1}, Status: {2}", ct.Id, ct.Action.Method, ct.Status);
//Prints: "ID: 1, Method: Void MyMethod(), Status: WaitingToRun"

ct.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Method: {1}, Status: {2}", ct.Id, ct.Action.Method, ct.Status);
//Prints: "ID: 1, Method: Void MyMethod(), Status: RanToCompletion"
```

Note that to access information about the method, you have to access `ct.Action.Method`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can override the ToString() method. This is the easy way
But what you are looking for are these classes:

- DebuggerDisplayAttribute
- DebuggerBrowsableAttribute

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx for more information